# How do I exclude a member from Linq-To-Sql mapping?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have this class:

```
public class MyClass {
    [Column(Name="StoredColumn", DbType="int")]
    public int Stored;

    public int ForDisplay {
       get { return Stored * 1000; }
    }
}
```

The point is `ForDisplay` is not to be stored in the database - I just need it for more convenient code.

I try to run an SQL query that returns a rowset and get this `InvalidOperationException`:

> Cannot assign value to member 'ForDisplay '. It does not define a setter.

I don't want `ForDisplay` to be touched by Linq-To-Sql. How do tell Ling-To-Sql to not touch it?

Comment: Not sure, but try making `ForDisplay` a [linq2sql computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.columnattribute.expression.aspx).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to tell Linq to Sql that it should not touch the "ForDisplay" property. Normally, all properties that are not specifically marked with the `Column` attribute are treated as transient part of your application logic and are not persisted or retrieved from the database.

However, if you want to retrieve some records from the database via a stored procedure, say `GetMyClasses`, then the designer will create a new class `GetMyClassesResult`. If you look at the generated code, then you will notice that the class is not decorated with the `Table` attribute. In that case the mapper assumes that *every* property must be assigned. If there is a property without corresponding value in the query then the mapper will try to set the property to default(T), but as there is no setter, the exception will be thrown.

Anyway, to make a long story short, just adding

```
[Table]
public class MyClass
{
  ...
}
```

to your class should fix the issue.

Comment: Could you please provide a vb version?

Answer (score 1):

You can extend linq2sql with partial classes. The key element is not to modify the original class but create an extra partial class:

```
 public partial class MyClass
 {
    public int ForDisplay {   
       get
       {
           return this._Stored * 1000; 
       }   
    }   
  }
```

Comment: This works great with tables.  It does not work with stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare the column as a computed column like that:

```
public class MyClass 
{ 
    [Column(Name="StoredColumn", DbType="int")]     
    public int Stored;      

    [Column(Name="ForDisplay", Expression="StoredColumn * 1000")]
    public int ForDisplay 
    {        
        get { return Stored * 1000; }     
    } 
}
```

That should work.

Comment: Tried - no changes in behavior.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was with the return value from a table value function where the model did not decorate

```
[Table]
```

on the class. I can confirm that adding [Table] against my extra partial class worked a treat

```
[Table]
public partial class MyClassFromTVF
{
        public int ForDisplay {
             get { return Stored * 1000; }
        }
}
```